# Dealing with Name/Auto Number on Junction object records

Tags: junction-object

I have a scenario where I am trying to be able to list multiple Tools that were used on a Job Site.  I have two custom object records, Tools and Job Sites, and a third Junction object, called 'Tools used on Job Site'. Both Tools and Job Sites have a Master-Detail to 'Tools used on Job Site'.  When I go to the related list on Job Site to add new Tools, there is a Name field that is mandatory, but doesn't make sense being there, as I already have the Job Site and Tools fields available.

Other option is to change the Data Type to Auto-number, but every time a record is added, the green bar pops up at the top, saying "Tools used on Job Site 001 has been created"...which doesn't make sense.

Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong here? It is repetitive for that Name field (or, auto number) to be there.  Thanks.

Comment: N.B. best practice would be to name the junction object as a singular noun like `JobSite Tool`

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, yes, you'll get a message like "Tools used on Job Site 001". That's standard functionality, and mostly unavoidable, unless you want to write some code to override the default UI. All records must have a Name, and your only two choices are required manual entry or auto-number.

Comment: Seems like something that should be able to be toggled on/off in the UI.  Any resources for coding this solution?